# Cisco EEM pass Syslog message to TCL script

Tags: cisco, syslog, cisco-eem

I'm on a Cisco 1811 with **IOS 15.1(3)T** - yes it's really old, but that probably doesn't matter here.

I have this TCL script that makes an HTTP POST to a destination and i want to pass in ANY Syslog message emitted by the system into the request body.

```
<< my own http_get implementation here >>

namespace import ::cisco::eem::*
namespace import ::cisco::lib::*

set url "http://some.url.out.there:8000"
set mystdin [gets stdin]
set res [http_get $url -query $mystdin]

puts "POSTed to url"
```

My Event Manager applet looks like this:

```
event manager applet TRIGGER
    event syslog occurs 1 pattern "%.*"
    action 2.0 policy sendevent.tcl $_syslog_msg
```

Now this works fine except that i'm not getting anything into `$mystdin`, so my request body is empty.

How do i pass in Event Manager's `$_syslog_msg` to the TCL script?
Maybe there's a way to query for "last Syslog event" from within the script without reading from `stdin`?

Comment: This seems like a real kludge. Why not set up a syslog server that gets all the syslog messages, and deal with this on the syslog server?

Comment: That would normally be the case. However this is a special case - there's zero infrastructure on-prem so everything needs to go to an HTTP endpoint.

Comment: You can have an off-site syslog server, too. If you can get to an HTTP server, you can get to a syslog server.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. What I'm trying to say is that in this particular scenario HTTP is all I have, can't talk to raw endpoints.

Comment: I think you are going to need to explain. If the device can connect to an HTTP server, the device can connect to a syslog server, and it has the built-in ability to automatically send syslog data to the syslog server. You could even run a syslog server on the same server as the HTTP server. I really don't understand the need for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Isn't Syslog UDP? If IOS can't package syslog events into HTTP requests then I can't use the built in feature.

Comment: What I am saying is that once you have it on a syslog server, you can manipulate it anyway you want. Once you have the data, then convert it to HTTP for display, or whatever. That is something you should do on the server. Trying to use the network device for this is a real kludge.

Comment: I fully understand your position, however I can't get the data to a Syslog server, thus my kludgy question. It's either HTTP straight from the box or bust.

Comment: If you can get the data to an HTTP server, you can get it to a syslog server. I really don't understand. What reason, as I have asked you to explain, do you have to say only HTTP can come from the router? Routers can route all types of traffic, and a router really has no idea if what it is routing is HTTP (TCP) or UDP. Routers route using IP, not a transport or application-layer protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, so

```
action policy POLICY_NAME $arg
```

doesn't pass arguments to the script - had to switch to

```
action cli command "tclsh flash:/script.tcl $arg"`
```

which does, HOWEVER...

EEM actions are unable to capture beyond a newline from a variable.
I did find a way out though - trim the newline from `$_syslog_msg` (newline is the first char) and assign to a new variable.

Here's the end-to-end solution:

```
CISCO-1811#sh run | s event
event manager directory user policy "flash:/"
event manager directory user library "flash:/"
event manager directory user repository tftp://1.1.1.3/
event manager applet TRIGGER_ON_SYSLOG
  event syslog occurs 1 pattern "%.*"
  action 1.0 string trimleft "$_syslog_msg"
  action 2.0 cli command "enable"
  action 2.1 cli command "tclsh flash:/sendevent.tcl \"$_string_result\""
```

`$_string_result` is an EEM built-in variable that collects the output of string trimleft

From http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/eem/command/eem-cr-book/eem-cr-a2.html:

> Use the `action string trimleft` command to trim a string from the left end of another string.
>   This command trims the characters specified by `string2` from the left end of `string1`. By default, `string2` corresponds to white space.
>
> The table below shows the built-in variable in which the result of the `action string trimleft` command is stored.
>
> **Built-in Variable**:
>   `$_string_result`
>
> **Description**:
>   The result of the `action string trimleft` command is stored in this variable.

The above is actually incomplete/misleading/or Cisco has no idea how the language they picked works:
`string trimleft` without a second argument trims **space, tab, newline, and CR** not just white space (See this: http://wiki.tcl.tk/10177).

#### sendevent.tcl

```
#...
# my own http_get implementation here
# ...

# My actual event code

set url "http://some.http.destination:8000"

# Event log message is passed in as "$argv 0".
# That's the first item in $argv (which is a list)
set rawmsg [lindex $argv 0]

# Strip quotes from syslog message
set cleanmsg [string map { "\"" "" } $rawmsg]

# Get the time stamp at source
set timestamp [clock format [clock seconds] -format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"]

set json "{
    \"RouterTimestamp\": \"$timestamp\",
    \"Message\": \"$cleanmsg\"
}\n"

# This makes a POST request. Yes a POST.
# Don't know, ask the TCL developers what's with the name :)
if {[catch {http_get $url -query $json} token]} {
    puts "HTTP POST request failed: $token"
} else {
    # Everything is fine
    puts "POST successful."
}
```

#### Result

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Host: some.http.destination
User-Agent: Snobu Speshul TCL HTTP/1.1 Client library // build 21
Connection: close
Content-Length: 151
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "RouterTimestamp": "2017-02-02T10:09:49",
    "Message": "*Feb  2 10:09:49.307: %CLEAR-5-COUNTERS: Clear counter on all interfaces by console"
}
```

GitHub repo here (code complete): https://github.com/snobu/cisco-syslog-over-http

Comment: If you have a complaint for Cisco, you will need to address that directly to Cisco. [networkengineering.se] is not a Cisco site.